# API Keys section missing in Dialogflow settings > General section

Tags: dialogflow-es

I could see API Keys section, when I initially created an agent and I could get the client access token under this and use this in my app successfully. But then, when I updated Dialogflow agent with some more input, it wasn't reflected, when I ran the app.
Then I thought, the client access token could have been updated and checked for API Keys section. To my surprise, this section is completely missing now. Even deleting the agent and recreating a new agent, didn't help. API Keys section is still missing. Please help

Comment: I don't think this is a question for stack overflow. It probably has nothing to do with your code.

Comment: Yeah. Not to do with my code. But the support section under dialogflow mentioned this is as one of the methods to seek support. If stack Overflow only deals with the code issues, sorry about it.

Comment: Valid questions can include ["software tools commonly used by programmers"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). Since the Dialogflow tools themselves are used by Dialogflow programmers, they are within scope of questions from developers. Showing the screen where you expected to see the keys, or showing how you were using the keys, may help provide a better answer.

Comment: Thanks. That's what I thought.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

API Keys were a feature of v1, which has been shut down.

You should be using Google Cloud service accounts with Dialogflow v2.

Comment: Oh! @Prisoner, Thanks for the answer! That clarifies. The funny thing is when I started using dialogflow just a couple of days back, it had this API keys section and now it disappeared. So, not sure if such an upgrade has happened within this period. But, now I do see under GOOGLE PROJECT section, a new entry called 'Service account' with a link that has a key for Dialogflow integration. Need to check the dialogflow docs to see how to use it. Thanks for the info.

Comment: Glad it clarifies! If an answer has helped, accepting and/or upvoting it is always appreciated. v1 was officially shut down on 31 May, but it may have taken them a few weeks to actually get around to turning it off.

Comment: done! New to actually ask questions in Stackoverflow :)